# Server Call Functions on Client in Java

Tags: java, comet

I have a web application. I need the web application to be able to call functions on the client. Assume I am able to have the client call into the server to establish a connection.

I have been looking into different ways to do this. One way is using  [Comet Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29) I would really prefer the server to be able to call the methods directly instead of sending messages though.

Is there a built in Java way of doing this? Or is there some other way this can be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like Java RMI might well be exactly what you're looking for.

Have a read over [the official documentation](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/index-jsp-136424.html).

Answer (score 0):

GWT (google web toolkit) can do this, check:

http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit-incubator/wiki/ServerPushFAQ

But I never use this. I always do pooling from client to server like

```
while(true){
   resp = ask_for_something();
   if (resp.has_something_to_do) { do_something(/* resp.action_or_etc */); }
   sleep(SLEEPTIME);
}
```

but in javascript context you can use setInterval and ajax with timeout